# iframes and css conflicts

Tags: css, iframe

This is a general question about iframes.

When including another full webpage within an iframe, is it possible for the "iframed" site's CSS stylesheet to conflict with the CSS for the outer document?

Answer (score 4):

No. The page  in iframe uses its own rendering context. For all practical purposes, it is a treated as a separate window.